# Are there any dangers in using mv (instead of cp followed by rm)?

Tags: mv

I'm a graduate student with access to a research group Linux cluster at my university. Over the years, I have accumulated many directories -- I guess "folders" is Windows/Mac terminology? -- in my home directory (`~`).  When I'm working on a new simulation, I create a new directory in my home directory using `mkdir` and then run the simulation in that directory.

But over time, I have accumulated many such directories in my home directory.  Now I want to move some of the directories into subdirectory.  For example, I might want to create a new directory called `simulations1_10` and then move the directories `simulation1`, `simulation2`, ... , `simulation10` into that directory -- so that the root of my home directory is more organized.

To do this, I could use `cp`.  For example:

```
cp -r simulation1/ simulations1_10/
```

would copy the directory `simulation1` (and all its contents) to the directory `simulations1_10`.  I could then remove `simulation1`.

But, my transfers *aren't* crossing filesystem boundaries, so `mv` is *much* faster than `cp`.  (`mv` of course also allows me to avoid the remove step.)  For example:

```
mv simulation1/ simulations1_10/
```

does the trick quickly (and unlike `cp`, `mv` is recursive by default).  According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/95029/133274) to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/94988/is-it-better-to-always-copy-and-delete-rather-than-move), `mv` is much faster because it "just updates the inode database in various directories."

My question is, are there any dangers in using `mv`?

I think that one danger is that if `mv` is interrupted (due to power failure, user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, etc) during a transfer, the file might become corrupted in both the source *and* the destination.  Is this correct?

Also, if I use `mv` *a lot*, is there a chance that the "inode database" will be updated too often, causing disk fragmentation or other hard drive/filesystem problems?

Comment: mv is not actually recursive.  It is merely moving one thing, the inode of the directory you specify.  Everything under that directory remains untouched.  Think of it as cutting a branch off a tree, and attaching it to a different place on the tree: you merely make one cut, rather than doing something to each twig & leaf.

Comment: @jamesqf Thank you!  I am a relatively novice user of Unix and Linux; is the inode of the directory sort of like a pointer to the data?

Comment: I don't think that's the question, but `mv a.txt b.txt` can be dangerous because it deletes `b.txt` without warning. Okay, so does `cp a.txt b.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

The `rename` function (that underlies the command `mv`, ["The mv utility shall perform actions equivalent to the rename() function"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mv.html)) is atomic (see POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html, that refers to the C standard):

> This rename() function is equivalent for regular files to that defined by the ISO C standard. Its inclusion here expands that definition to include actions on directories and specifies behavior when the new parameter names a file that already exists. That specification requires that the action of the function be atomic.

(But see this for caveats: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322074/88983.)

Interrupted operations, be it by Ctrl-C or otherwise, should never result in partially-transferred files. Indeed, as you mention, a single-filesystem `mv` doesn't actually copy any file contents, only file metadata. The worst that should happen on that front is to see partially-moved *directories* (if you do `mv a b c dest`, it is possible to interrupt and have only e.g. `a` moved into `dest`, but all files and their contents will have been moved properly), not partially-moved regular files.

About your inode side question, I would say it's generally not a concern; updating inodes to move just a few directories around is a low-overhead, routine operation (file content writes happening on the same filesystem should be a much greater potential performance hit or fragmentation cause, depending on the specific filesystem type).

Comment: Thanks so much!  When you say, "File content writes happening on the same filesystem should be a much greater potential performance hit or fragmentation cause, depending on the specific filesystem type," does that mean that `cp` might actually cause *more* fragmentation, etc than `mv`?

Comment: I was thinking of other users of the same cluster doing writes concurrently with your cleanup operations, but it is also true that copying files is going to be a lot more write-intensive than moving them, and is more likely to cause fragmentation (although fragmentation generally isn't a big concern on typical Unix filesystems).

Comment: Note that POSIX only guarantees atomicity when the target already exists. It doesn't when the target doesn't exist, though most unix systems do offer this guarantee for their native filesystems.