# cp vs. mv: which operation is more efficient?

Tags: cp, mv

I find myself moving reasonably large amount of data (20+ GB) from one directory tree to other. Often times they are on the same filesystem but sometimes they are on different ones. I do `cp` just to preserve the original data just-in-case. Once the copy is done I delete the original data after verifying that the data has been copied alright. Sometimes I just do `mv` if I feel too lazy to clean original data afterwards. However, I am wondering, from purely technical point of view, which operation is more efficient? Why?

Comment: When moving data across filesystems, neither is more efficient - they're about the same.   the `cp`,verify,`rm` strategy is safer because it is easier to recover from an unexpected error - e.g. the `mv` or `cp` failing partway through due to disk full error or (if the destination fs is a network share) the network going down, etc.  With `cp` you still have your complete original data in its original directory structure.  With `mv` you have some of your data in the original dir, some in the target dir, and re-merging them may be difficult (esp. if the target dir contains other data).

Comment: BTW if `cp` fails before completion due to error, once you have resolved the error you can complete the `cp` from where it left off by using `rsync`.  In fact, you can use `rsync` instead of `cp` right from the start.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically, `mv` is not atomic when the source and destination are on different filesystems, it is actually `cp` + `unlink()`. So at first `mv` will copy the file and then call `unlink()` to remove the file from the directory's list of entries.

So in this case, AFAIU whether you `cp` and then `rm` (`unlink()`) or use `mv` directly is totally your personal preference.

Whereas while `mv` -ing within the same filesystem, you should use `mv` as its atomic within the same filesystem (calls `rename()`) so less overhead.

*Thanks @muru and @psusi for the pointing out the FS dependent behavior.*

Comment: (…across filesystems). In the same filesystem, it's atomic.

Comment: More specifically, in the same filesystem it simply calls `rename()`.

Comment: @muru Didn't know that..thanks..edited..

Comment: Nice post about that behaviour: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193436/are-there-any-dangers-in-using-mv-instead-of-cp-followed-by-rm

Comment: In the case of `mv` in file transfers could the `unlink()` part sometimes fail?

Comment: @Viesturs Of course e.g. permission issue.

Comment: What if I call `mv file1 file2` and the transmission (`cp` part) fails. Will `unlink()` be called in this case?

Comment: @Viesturs Nope.