# In RHEL/CentOS 7, does mv actually do a cp & rm on the same filesystem?

Tags: centos, filesystems, rhel, cp, mv

In light of the answers to two [previous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277412/6388) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193436/6388), it *seems* that under RHEL/CentOS 7 `mv` even on the same filesystem is actually doing a `cp` then `rm`.

In previous editions of CentOS/RHEL, a `mv` on the same filesystem (even from a deep directory to a new deep directory) was very fast even on large files (say collections of installation media or large videos).

However, on my personal CentOS server, when watching what `mv` is actually doing when moving large files, it's taking as long as a `cp` followed by `rm`.

Which makes me wonder why the behavior has apparently changed from just being a wrapper to `rename()` (as per the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) standard).

Is this correct? And, if so, why did the `mv` utility change behavior in CentOS 7?

Comment: looking at the questions you linked I see no indication that mv would do cp + rm on any version when using the same filesystem. Nobody seems to claim so. Can you clarify what kind of test case you have for that?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `mount`?  I suspect there are two different filesystems involved.

Comment: @Wildcard it may have to do with going from one md device to another in the LVM - which would make sense of i am crossing a physical device under the hood.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CentOS 7.2 `mv` command will try to use the `rename(3)` call.

eg  if I do `strace mv X Y` then I see in the output

```
rename("X", "Y")                        = 0
```

So we can see that `mv` successfully called rename.

If, instead I try to rename this directory to another disk:

```
rename("X", "/home/sweh/X")             = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
```

We can see that `mv` tried to use the `rename()` call and this failed.  At this point it starts to do recursive work

```
rmdir("/home/sweh/X")                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkdir("/home/sweh/X", 0700)             = 0
lstat("/home/sweh/X", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "X", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
```

Here we can see it's made the target directory, and then started to read the current directory to do the slow copy/remove.

So we can conclude that `mv` will try to use the fast `rename()` call and only fall back to the slow version if this fails.

Comment: clarification on initial question - I see the "cp then rm" on large files and directory trees. But just single files are [apparently] renamed

Comment: I just created a tree 100 directories deep and `mv X Y` still just called `rename()`.   I also created 100 subdir's of `X` and it still just called `rename`.  Are you using an odd filesystem (NTFS? SSHFS?) that may not support `rename()` ?

Comment: Nope. ext4. And like I said in my clarification, individual files seem to rename whereas groups seem to not

Comment: I also created 100 files and did `mv * ../Z` and saw it call `rename()` 100 times; once for each filename that matches the command line ('cos shell globbing expands it).

Comment: If you do `mv <1millionfiles> anotherdir` then it will call `rename()` 1 million times.  Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with depth of the tree being moved? I can replicate it on "deep" moves (say 5+ deep to 5+ deep with nothing in common but /). Shallower moves seem to be doing rename though.

Comment: I did it with a 100 directory deep tree and it was a single `rename()` call.

Comment: Very odd. Thanks for diving in on this to see if you can replicate it :)

Comment: @warren "nothing in common but /" - could it be going across non-obvious different filesystems?

Comment: @Izkata perhaps :)

Comment: @warren: use `df` on the src and dst, to see if they're different mount points.  Note that `rename(2)` doesn't work even across bind-mounts, though, so even if the device column is the same for both, it can't just rename if the "mounted on" column differs.  Oh nvm, just saw your comment on the question.  Of course it can't just `rename` between two separate ext4 filesystems on different MD devices.  That would mean you'd have one filesystem referring to data that's part of the other filesystem, so they'd have to know about each other.  But that's the opposite of separate filesystems.

Comment: @PeterCordes - as I've gone deeper, it's not consistent behavior, which is what leads me to think it's crossing physical devices *sometimes*, and that's just what I happened to catch when I posted the question.

Comment: @warren: What do you mean "not consistent"?  Is your VFS setup so complex that it's not obvious when you're moving between filesystems (`rename` always fails, mv has to copy) vs. within a single filesystem (`rename` always works)?  Maybe it copied so fast that you thought it actually just renamed, sometimes?  If the data was already hot in disk cache, it will be very fast because it's just a memory->memory copy.  `mv` has to wait for data to be read, but can exit before it's synced to disk.  (Or if the files aren't too big, it can be very fast to read them in).

Comment: @PeterCordes what I've been testing against have been collections of large files (several 3GB ISOs). What it appears to be doing is sometimes the rename works, and sometimes it doesn't. The sometimes it doesn't seems to be when it's crossing a physical device under the logical volume (that sits atop a RAID). Iow, it actually is trying the rename - but it is crossing a physical boundary, it cannot (which makes sense)